# Не может найти модуль Django

Tags: django, django-admin

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file_project.upload_app'
Не знаю в чем проблема и как ее решить
[image: код]

Comment: Уберите file_project и оставьте только upload_app

Comment: urls.py заново создать в upload_app?

Comment: Не надо ничего создавать, просто file_project с точкой сотрите и всё

Comment: Спасибо помогло